# How to reslove Singltion class leak issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, singleton

I used following code in `Singleton_Newmark.h` file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Singleton_Newmark : NSObject
{

    NSString *strxpos;
    NSString *strypos;
    NSString *strindex;
    NSString *strtag;



}
@property (nonatomic) NSString *strxpos;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *strypos;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *strindex;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *strtag;


+(Singleton_Newmark *)sharedInstance;
@end



   Following code used Singleton_Newmark.m file

#import "Singleton_Newmark.h"

@implementation Singleton_Newmark
@synthesize  strxpos,strypos,strindex,strtag;
+(Singleton_Newmark *)sharedInstance
{
    static Singleton_Newmark *sharedInstance = nil;
    if (!sharedInstance) {
        sharedInstance=[[Singleton_Newmark alloc]init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    strxpos=nil;
    strypos=nil;
    strindex=nil;
    strtag=nil;
}
@end
```

I insert value in the singleton class object.

```
Singleton_Newmark *obj=[[Singleton_Newmark alloc]init];
                  obj.strxpos=@"Some string";
        obj.strypos=@"Some string";
        obj.strindex=@"Some string";
        obj.strtag=@"Some string";
```

Again read from the singleton class object

```
Singleton_Newmark *obj=[Singleton_Newmark sharedInstance];
        obj=[Dict objectForKey:@"forkey"];
```

Here i received leak message from analyze:

```
 Value stored to 'obj' during its initialization is never read
```

But I received the analyze leak error in the last line( again read from...). How resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way for implementing the single ton pattern is to hide init method. You can achieve by below way:

```
- (id)init __attribute__((unavailable("cannot use init for this class, use +(Singleton_Newmark*)sharedInstance instead")));
```

This will block the user to use `init` method. So they will be forced to use `sharedInstance` method only. That will provide you clean representation of your code even when you publish it as library.

This what you will write in your method:

```
+ (Singleton_Newmark *)sharedInstance {
    static Singleton_Newmark *sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [self new];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
Singleton_Newmark *obj=[[Singleton_Newmark alloc]init];
```

with this line

```
Singleton_Newmark *obj = [Singleton_Newmark sharedInstance];
```

**__________ EDIT (forget this part and read comments): __________**

and move

```
   static Singleton_Newmark *sharedInstance = nil;
```

outside of

```
+(Singleton_Newmark *)sharedInstance{ … }
```

method (or you reset it each time and never reuse it as a singleton)

**__________  END EDIT __________**

if you use the normal `alloc` + `init` methods then you are not using your class as a singleton, and you are using a new instance each time you pass that line, and never releasing it, that's why you have a leak memory.

For that you need to use your static method `sharedInstance`, so you get a new instance the first time, don't release it, and then you get that same instance the next time you pass that code.

Comment: "(or you reset it each time and never reuse it as a singleton)" This is not true because `sharedInstance` is being declared as `static`.

Comment: @DrBeardface: you're right for this point, i'll add a note, tks